# Can I migrate WCF SOAP service to .Net 6 with no changes at client side?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, basichttpbinding

I have an old .Net Framework 4.8 WCF SOAP service using `basicHttpBinding`. It is used by a lot of different clients. We're thinking of moving everything to .Net 6 in Linux containers.
Is there a way to migrate the service so that clients don't have to change their `web.configs` and code? I know the new .Net doesn't play well with WCF but maybe someone has experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

The replacement for wcf in.NET 6 is **CoreWCF**. It is **Cross-Platform** so it can run on linux.

CoreWCF supports most of the features in wcf including `BasicHttpBinding`.
However, it requires updating the code accordingly rather than making no changes.

And you can follow the links below for more info:

[CoreWCF 1.0 has been Released, WCF for .NET Core and .NET 5+](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/).

[CoreWCF in Github](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF).